# How to create multi color vertical bar chart in d3.js using specific json data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```js
data = [
  {
    "name":'A',
    "frequency":10,
    "target":20,
  },
  {
    "name":'B',
    "frequency":20,
    "target":10,
  },
]
```

Here in bar up to target need some x color after that y color.

[Example bar chart with colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WoTI.png)

Comment: I think you need a stacked bar chart. Here is a code example: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_basicWide.html

Comment: hi you can check this library that use d3 js https://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html

Answer (score 0):

A vertical bar chart with multiple colors/data per bar is a **Stacked Bar Chart**

There are multiple tutorials on the internet you can find when you search for stacked bar charts.

Bilhasry Ramadhony already provided a link with a very simple example: [https://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html](http://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_basicWide.html)

If you are looking for more details, here is another example: [d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_basicWide.html](http://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_basicWide.html)

Comment: its , an different one here i need the stack as till target one color, and frequency another color.
Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/64nNNt3aHZ17dqn3o4jX?p=preview&preview

in the above axample target marked with a path but needed rect even for that.